# Best way to convert point coordinate (x, y) to unique token Id

Tags: nft, solidity-0.8.x, overflow

I have a map which has width as 100 and height as 100, meaning ​`100 * 100` size map.
The origin is at the center and its coordinate is (0, 0).

So `-50 < x < 50`  and `-50 < y < 50`.
I want to match each cell on the map to unique NFT.

I found exact code on github.

https://github.com/decentraland/land/blob/7cd58341007d1d8884a22e16a726e133405b3bac/contracts/land/LANDRegistry.sol#L135

This is the code snippet

**Encoding part**

```js
  function encodeTokenId(int x, int y) external pure returns (uint) {
    return _encodeTokenId(x, y);
  }

  function _encodeTokenId(int x, int y) internal pure returns (uint result) {
    require(
      -1000000 < x && x < 1000000 && -1000000 < y && y < 1000000,
      "The coordinates should be inside bounds"
    );
    return _unsafeEncodeTokenId(x, y);
  }

  function _unsafeEncodeTokenId(int x, int y) internal pure returns (uint) {
    return ((uint(x) * factor) & clearLow) | (uint(y) & clearHigh);
  }
```

**Decoding part**

```js
  function decodeTokenId(uint value) external pure returns (int, int) {
    return _decodeTokenId(value);
  }

  function _unsafeDecodeTokenId(uint value) internal pure returns (int x, int y) {
    x = expandNegative128BitCast((value & clearLow) >> 128);
    y = expandNegative128BitCast(value & clearHigh);
  }

  function _decodeTokenId(uint value) internal pure returns (int x, int y) {
    (x, y) = _unsafeDecodeTokenId(value);
    require(
      -1000000 < x && x < 1000000 && -1000000 < y && y < 1000000,
      "The coordinates should be inside bounds"
    );
  }
```

These are the constants used above code.

```js
    uint256 constant clearLow = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000000000000000000000000000;
    uint256 constant clearHigh = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;
    uint256 constant factor = 0x100000000000000000000000000000000;
```

This works exactly as supposed for positive `x` value and all `y` values.
i.e

```js
(2, 2)  <-> 680564733841876926926749214863536422914
(2, -2) <-> 1020847100762815390390123822295304634366
```

But for negative values, it fails.
I think this is because overflow happens on following line for negative `x` values when multiplying `factor`.

```js
    return ((uint(x) * factor) & clearLow) | (uint(y) & clearHigh);
```

The referencing project works fine with this code well as solidity version is `0.4.23`.
But my contract is using `0.8.5`.

I don't care what the solution kind will be. What I want is encoding/decoding `(x, y) <-> tokenId` is possible.
How can I acheive this for version `0.8.x`?

Comment: If negativity is an issue, you could just add 50 to all numbers before encoding, and deduct 50 after decoding

Comment: The point is the map can be expanded further. Of course map will have limit width and height so I can add that for all negative values. But I wanna know if there is more beautiful solution.